# Alternative to udev functionality on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, udev

I'm trying to create a custom file/check in check out script for external hardrives, however part of the script is from a Linux machine, which I have tested works fine, but uses *udevinfo*, OS X doesn't have udev, so is there anything that offers the same functionality?

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a EXTERNAL_DISKS
declare -a INTERNAL_DISKS

for disk in /dev/[sh]d[a-z]; do
     eval `udevinfo -q env -n $disk`
     [ "$ID_BUS" = "usb" ] && EXTERNAL_DISKS=( ${EXTERNAL_DISKS[@]} $disk )
     [ "$ID_BUS" = "scsi" ] && INTERNAL_DISKS=( ${INTERNAL_DISKS[@]} $disk )
 done

 echo "Internal disks: ${INTERNAL_DISKS[@]}"
 echo "External disks: ${EXTERNAL_DISKS[@]}"
```

Anybody know any alternatives? Or a way this could be accomplished on OSX using bash?

Comment: I think I have found a workaround using diskutil, but if anybody has any suggestions I am open to them.

Comment: You are likely to get more satisfactory answers if you explain why already submitted answers aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from plistlib import readPlistFromString as rPFS
from subprocess import *

def shell(cmd):
    return Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

disks = {False: [], True: []}   
for disk in rPFS(shell('diskutil list -plist'))['WholeDisks']:
    disks[rPFS(shell('diskutil info -plist ' + disk))['Internal']].append(disk)

print "Internal disks: " + ' '.join(disks[True])    
print "External disks: " + ' '.join(disks[False])
```

Answer (score 1):

IOKit manages devices, DiskArbitration manages mass storage devices on top of that. Neither has much in the way of a scripting interface.